# Regular Expression pattern using gsub in r- get a small pattern in the middle of a larger pattern from xml file

Tags: r, regex

everyone. 
I am completely new to regex in r, and i run into a problem when trying to retrieve a smaller set of pattern in the middle of a larger pattern using tagged xml file.

Here, i have a three-word sequence "reinforce the advantage" tagged by BNC (British National Corpus) Basic (C5) Tagset system. In specific, i want to only retrieve the three lemmatized words immediately after every "hw=" in this long sequence.

```
<w c5=VVI hw=reinforce pos=VERB>reinforce </w><w c5=AT0 hw=the pos=ART>the </w><w c5=NN2 hw=advantage pos=SUBST>advantages </w>
```

Can anyone please offer a possible solution with gsub or other functions in r? Many thanks in advance!

NF

Comment: The downvote is probably happening because you are suggesting parsing XML using regex.

Comment: Oh...I did not know that, this is my first time to post a question here. Thanks for telling me this.

Comment: If your problem got solved please [choose an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
vec <- "<w c5=VVI hw=reinforce pos=VERB>reinforce </w><w c5=AT0 hw=the pos=ART>the </w><w c5=NN2 hw=advantage pos=SUBST>advantages </w>"

m <- gregexpr("(?<=hw=)\\S+", vec, perl = T)
regmatches(vec, m)

# [[1]]
# [1] "reinforce" "the"       "advantage"
```

---

copied from regex101.com

```
/
(?<=hw=)\S+
/

Positive Lookbehind (?<=hw=)

Assert that the Regex below matches
hw= matches the characters hw= literally (case sensitive)

\S+ matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])

+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,
giving back as needed (greedy)
```

---

first `?unlist` then collapse (`?paste0`)

```
paste0(unlist(
    regmatches(vec, m)
), collapse = " ")

# [1] "reinforce the advantage"
```

Comment: Hi, Andre. Many thanks!! I tried your code, it worked! But the result looked something like "c(\reinforce\, \the\, \advantage\)", how do i make the result a sequence like "reinforce the advantage" instead of separate words? Excuse me if that is a silly question because i just began using r to process text.

Comment: It might be worth the investment to use an xpath parser here instead of a regex.